# How to find the window's dirty region when WindowProc recieves a WM_PAINT message...?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, gdi, winapi

I have an inhouse API written in C++ (no MFC), implemented on top of win32 API. My app is drawing the whole window for each WM_PAINT call. Is there a way i could find only the dirty/inval region so that i can optimize my draw functions to draw only in the views that intersect with the dirty region.

I tried the following code between BeginPaint - EndPaint statements and failed horribly. whole window was black. If i set Optimize flag to 0, the window draws fine but the drawing is too slow. Any suggestions...??.

```
#if Optimize
// get the inval region and pass it down
    HRGN invalRegion = CreateRectRgn(0,0,0,0);  
    int retVal = ::GetClipRgn( myHDC,invalRegion);  
    Assert (retVal != -1);  
    if(retVal == 0)         
       return;     // nothing to draw.  
    else if(retVal == 1)        
       Draw(invalRegion); // a valid dirty region handle.   
    else
#endif
       Draw(NULL); // this results in drawing calls to all views in the window.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `rcPaint RECT` from the `PAINTSTRUCT`? GetClipRgn's [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144866(VS.85).aspx) specifically say it does *not* refer to the clipping region created by BeginPaint, but only those explicitly selected in via `SelectClipRgn`.